# replace tuple in list of tuples - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

Hey guys I want to be able to replace a tuple in a list of tuples. Here is what I am thinking:

```
let lst = [("john",3), ("greg",3), ("tom",2), ("rob",7), ("jason",4), ("tev",7)]
```

I want to be able to drop any tuple, say ("rob",7) from the list and then replace it with a new tuple ("ain",3).
In the end my final list will look something like this:

```
lst = [("john",3), ("greg",3), ("tom",2), ("ain",3), ("jason",4), ("tev",7)]
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: A different container type may be more appropriate than lists for these kinds of operations. For example, consider [Data.Set](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Set.html) or [Data.Map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can't be done.  Haskell is a pure functional language, so once a variable has a value, it keeps that value for good.

However, you can easily compute a new list from the old

```
map (\ x -> if x == ("rob",7) then ("ain",3) else x) lst
```

Comment: It's kind of disingenuous to say "it can't be done" because it can be done, just not in the same way that you would do it in an impure language, and it _can_ be done with similar performance characteristics (see: finger trees, for example) although you wouldn't be able to use the builtin list type of course.

Comment: By "it can't be done", I meant that Haskell doesn't have variable reassignment (:=).  I don't think finger trees change that. (However, thanks for mentioning them -- I actually wasn't familiar with them and they look interesting.) In a sense StateMonads do give Haskell the ability to change "variable" values, but I suspect the OP isn't quite ready for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
replaceTuple :: [(String, Int)] -> (String, Int) -> (String, Int) -> [(String, Int)]
replaceTuple tups old new = map check tups where
    check tup | tup == old = new
              | otherwise  = tup


main = print $ replaceTuple [("john",3), ("greg",3), ("tom",2), ("rob",7), ("jason",4), ("tev",7)] ("tev", 7) ("newperson", 9001)
```

This will (as you can see from the type annotation) only work for lists of (String, Int), which is what you have. You could define a more general replace function however, with the type signature of `replace :: Eq b => [b] -> b -> b -> [b]`. `b` must be an instance of the `Eq` type class because we're comparing elements, that's what "Eq b => ..." means.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you *can* do:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map

lst = Map.fromList [("john",3), ("greg",3), ("tom",2), ("rob",7), ("jason",4), ("tev",7)]

lst2 = Map.insert "ain" 3 $ Map.delete "rob" lst
```

If you're using interprested Haskell, the procedure is basically the same:

```
Prelude> import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map
Prelude Data.Map.Lazy> let lst = Map.fromList [("john",3), ("greg",3), ("tom",2), ("rob",7),     ("jason",4), ("tev",7)]
Prelude Data.Map.Lazy> lst
fromList [("greg",3),("jason",4),("john",3),("rob",7),("tev",7),("tom",2)]
Prelude Data.Map.Lazy> let lst2 = Map.insert "ain" 3 $ Map.delete "rob" lst
Prelude Data.Map.Lazy> lst2
fromList [("ain",3),("greg",3),("jason",4),("john",3),("tev",7),("tom",2)]
```

Note that "ain" is not necessarily in the same "place" in the Map that "rob" was. However, Maps don't have a notion of ordering like lists do.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make edits inside a list, I usually find the easiest way is to break the list up with `span` or `break` or `splitAt`, make changes, and then glue it back together with `++`. So in this case I'd do:

```
case break (\ (key,val) -> key == "rob") lst of
  (_, []) -> error "key not found! :("
  (xs, _ : ys) -> xs ++ ("ain", 3) : ys
```

Note that if you use [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) then there's a function `update` which does exactly the thing you want, and faster.